# Display text in real HTML in red instead of displaying text with color code as {color:#de350b}duchesse{color}

Tags: java, html, jsoup, jira

I am using the following code and I am trying to print the following code into HTML:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import com.opensymphony.util.TextUtils
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.comments.*
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import groovy.xml.*
import grrovy.util.*; 
import org.xml.sax.InputSource; 
import java.io.*; 
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
def commentManager = ComponentAccessor.getCommentManager()

Comment comment = commentManager.getLastComment(issue)

if(comment != null) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH)
    
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    //the line below retrieves {color:#de350b}duchesse{color}
    def body = comment.body
     
   
     

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   
   
    
        
        String html = "<html><body><h1></h1><h1>"+body+"</h1></body></html>";
        System.out.println(html);           // original

        Document doc2 = Jsoup.parse(html);   // pretty print HTML
        System.out.println(doc2.toString());
        return doc2
   
}
```

My output is under the form: {color:#de350b}duchesse{color}
but I would like the output to be in real displayable HTML which in this case means that only "duchesse" should be displayed in red instead of {color:#de350b}duchesse{color}.

How can I fix this?

Comment: And if you want it in red you would need to replace `/{color:#de350b}(\w+){color}/,\`<span class="red">$1</span>\`)`  or similar

Comment: def body = comment.body retrieves {color:#de350b}duchesse{color}, I  would like the process to be automated for any color, so I don't want to replace each color code with the code snippet you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression with two capturing groups. The first one will match the color and the second one will get the message. Then you can replace whole matched text with
`<font color="......."> ... </font>`.
So after `def body = comment.body` use this code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{color:(#......)\\}(.*)\\{color\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(body);
if (m.find()) {
    String color = m.group(1);
    String content = m.group(2);
    body = body.replace(m.group(0), "<font color=\"" + color + "\">" + content + "</font>");
}
```